# how to Loop on a string digit "0001"

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblPiglets ORDER BY ID DESC"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.Read() Then
            Do
                Dim week, pig, newpig As String
                week = dr("Week").ToString()
                pig = dr("PigletNumber").ToString
                If mtWeek.Text = week Then
                   ' check if same week was entered, if true, I tried something like this 
                   ' For i As Integer = pig To mtPig.Text
                   '   MsgBox - this is only to test whether its executing the code that I want
                   ' Next
                   ' But msgbox never displayed, loop doesn't recognize 0010 as it is
                End If
            Loop While dr.Read
        Else
        End If
    End Using
```

Sample Data:
[image]
What I am doing is to auto generate/save a list of of piglets.

*How it works:* User inputs WEEK and SOWORDER then the number of new born piglets, say 10. The result will be the picture above.

*However:* (code above) If the user added another on WEEK=01 but a new SOWORDER=02(mother pig), the result must be: `01 02 0011`, because its on the same week.

*My question is:* (based on what I've tried) How can I read `0010` as Integer as it is *to a certain number the user inputs*. Check comment on code.

If you guys have some other workaraounds, let me know :)

Comment: use a SQL query that begins to match the question/problem.  SELECT FROM tblPiglets WHERE Week = 1 AND SOW = 2 should give you those piglets.  you dont have to display them - data can be used in code to provide a solution

Comment: the query that I used is to get the last inserted data, in which the next data number will be based. Check whether the numbering will continue or create a new one.

Comment: From the looks of it your trying to use pigletnumbers as integers but looking at them these are in the format of decimals not integers.

Comment: If you need to compare integers, *store integers in the data*. `PigletNumber` should be integer values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, and then you simply convert the user input to an integer and compare directly. Format data for display, instead of storing the display values, and you'll make your work much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings and you should compare integers:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblPiglets ORDER BY ID DESC"
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If dr.Read() Then
    Do
        Dim week, pig, newpig As String
        week = dr("Week").ToString()
        pig = dr("PigletNumber").ToString
        If mtWeek.Text = week Then
                For i As Integer = CInt(pig) + 1 To CInt(pig) + CInt(mtPig.Text)
                    MessageBox.Show(i)
                Next
            End If
    Loop While dr.Read
Else
End If
End Using
```

Comment: Why didn't you allow my edit? I only used CInt on the `For Loop` case.

Comment: I need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits. Your suggestion was rejected by three other people. Sorry, I have edited the answer as you suggested by myself.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know something like that. Why'd you think they rejected? I think there is nothing wrong instead of posting another answer, right?

Comment: I think edition is to correct or format something. They understood that what you have done is commenting, which intends to improve the answer.